# Неккоректные русские символы в базе postgresql

Tags: postgresql, кодировка, java

Добрый день.
Есть одна небольшая бага с кодировкой некоторых русских символов, а именно с буквами "с", "я" (пока были замечены только они).

Дело в том, что при регистрации пользователь указывает имя и фамилию, эти параметры передаются через ajax в java servlet который записывает в базу эти данные, в результате получаются такие кракозябры:
Пет�?
Иванов

Кодировка везде (при отправке запроса в contenttype, в meta теге html страницы) указана utf-8. Не могу понять в чём причина.

Comment: вы бы хоть версию postgresql указали.

Comment: 9.3. База создана с кодировкой utf-8

Comment: какой JDBC драйвер? 
url подлючения к базе?

Comment: Я использую PGPoolingDataSource из библиотеки postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc4.jar

Comment: разобрались?

Comment: К сожалению нет...

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую ознакомиться с документацией, в частности с разделом [22.3. Character Set Support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/multibyte.html)
Проверьте с какой кодировкой была инициирована база данных initdb
Проверьте еще раз с какими параметрами создавали базу данных createdb

Возможно необходимо принудительно выставить кодировку в URL строке подключения к базе данных.
jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/<название БД>?charSet=UTF8

Comment:  1. charSet имеет смысл до версий 7.3
 2. sudo -u postgres createdb -E UTF8 -T template0 --lc-collate=ru_RU.UTF-8 --lc-ctype=ru_RU.UTF-8 topology_store